# AMQP unable to receive message back from listener

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a issue with Receive message back from Listener to publisher. I am getting
**AmqpReplyTimeoutException **. Below is the code of Publisher from where i am publishing to queue.

```
for(CsvWrapperPojo item : items){

        resultList.addAll(item.getDbResultList());

        for(CSVPojo pojo :item.getQueueRequestList()){




            sampleResponseMessageRabbitConverterFuture= asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("spring-boot-rabbitmq-Interactive.async_Solve_InteractiveMsg", "Interactive_RequestQueue", pojo);
            //CSVPojo res =(CSVPojo)rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("spring-boot-rabbitmq-Interactive.async_Solve_InteractiveMsg", "Interactive_RequestQueue", pojo);
            System.out.println("heyyyyyy:" + sampleResponseMessageRabbitConverterFuture.get().getLatitute());
        //resultList.add(res);
        //resultList.add(sampleResponseMessageRabbitConverterFuture.get());
        }

    }
```

By using it i am able to publish to queue, i have subscriber code below.

```
 @EnableRabbit
public class ListenerQueueSubscriber {

    @RabbitHandler
    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = "simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory", queues ="Interactive_RequestQueue")
    public void subscribeToRequestQueue(@Payload CSVPojo sampleRequestMessage, Message message) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("inside listener");
    sampleRequestMessage.setResult("Hello");
    Thread.sleep(120000);
    System.out.println("After sleep:" +sampleRequestMessage.getLongitude());
    //return sampleRequestMessage;
}
}
```

By using above subscriber able to listen message and i am appending "**Hello** and put sleep for 2 minutes and after that i have to receive the message back to publisher from where i have published . But unfortunately not receiving the message with **Hello** appended getting **AmqpReplyTimeoutException **. Can please help to achieve this behavior.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Please, take a look here for possible solution: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-spring-amqp.html. Not sure though, how you expect not to get `AmqpReplyTimeoutException` if you sleep for two mins before sending reply...

Comment: Thanks Bilan for your response. I tried to set receive timeout for 5mins. asyncRabbitTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(300000); Eventhough getting same error. Tried removing Thread.sleep but no luck. I have to return object in my listener class? to receive in publisher

Comment: Yes, you have to return indeed

Comment: Thanks Bilan. It worked. Last question from my side : is there any way to set ReceiveTimeout (asyncRabbitTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(300000)) to until it get response from Subscriber, i mean instead of putting a static milliseconds is there any value we can put to wait until it get response back from subscriber?

Comment: Is that feature available? or it behave/have the capability  like "until a reply Message is received or as long as the timeout, whichever is longer" manner already?

Comment: Well, you can set it to something definitely big, but that's not going to be practical. Since your producer and consumer are distributed there is no guarantee that something won't happen in between. So, in the real world it is going to be resource wasting to wait forever in the case we may lose reply somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!! just to make sure if my consumer take a bit long time to return message back to publisher will it wait until it receives the message back? or will it get timeout exception?

Comment: It will wait maximum the timeout. If reply comes earlier, that's good for you. Otherwise it doesn't work: the consumer fully doesn't block producer because there is a RabbitMQ Broker between them. So, producer has to do something on its own to wait some time for reply. Nothing more can be done.

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks for your clarifications Bilan.